# Slash interpolation in JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, http

I have got the following url:

```
'/aaa/bbb/ccc/' + part + '/ddd/eee'
```

`part` is variable which contains '/'. I need to interpolate it, because Rails backend catches this route as incorrect (404 error), but `part` value must be just part or URL. How can I do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode this `url` to make it valid url. Secondly I think you should pass this part as query parameter. Apparently you can do something like

```
 '/aaa/bbb/ccc/' + encodeURIComponent(part) + '/ddd/eee'
```

You can pass it as query parameter like

```
'/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee?part='+encodeURIComponent(part)
```